# Put 2 info from different cols in 1 dropdown menu

Tags: php, forms, drop-down-menu, multiple-columns

I want to put 2 information in 1 drop-down menu. I'm doing a school system. So for classes drop-down menu, I would like to put [classname (year)] in the drop-down-menu. The information were in a same table but different cols. I can only manage to display the class id / class name only.

```
 <tr>
  <td>Class</td>
  <td>
    <select name="classname" id="textbox">
     <option>---- Class Name   ------</option>
       <?php
         $class_name=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM class_tbl");
         while($row=mysql_fetch_array($class_name)){
       ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $row['class_name'];?>"> <?php echo $row['class_id'];?> </option>
       <?php 
         }
       ?>
    </select>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: what happens when you try to output the year like `<?php echo $row['your_year_column_name'];?>`?

Comment: You might want to consider using mysqli or PDO since mysql is deprecated / out of date.

Answer (score 0):

You should concat the 2 information in that field.

Do like this:

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['class_id'];?>"> <?php echo $row['class_name']." (".$row['year'].")";?> </option>
```

Write your table columns in `$row` array in place of my code.

Let me know for further help.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see naything wrong, are you sure you are not just mispelling some syntax?

```
<tr>
  <td>Class</td>
    <td>
     <select name="classname" id="textbox">
      <option>---- Class Name   ------</option>
       <?php
         $class_name=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM class_tbl");
         while($row=mysql_fetch_array($class_name)){
       ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['class_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['class_name']."(".$row['year'].")"; ?>  </option>
        <?php 
          }
        ?>
     </select>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

As you see i swapped the id and description position.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of displaying class name you need to swap positions of id and name.This should be the basic structure if you want to display name and get the selected id.

```
<option value="option_id">Option Name</option>
```

So for your problem it should be something like this.

```
 <tr>
  <td>Class</td>
  <td>
    <select name="classname" id="textbox">
     <option>---- Class Name   ------</option>
       <?php
         $class_name=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM class_tbl");
         while($row=mysql_fetch_array($class_name)){
       ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $row['class_id'];?>"> <?php echo $row['class_name'];?> </option>
       <?php 
         }
       ?>
    </select>
   </td>
 </tr>
```